# Understanding haskell's lazyness (foldl)

Tags: haskell

I have a infinite list of key value pairs `[(k, v)]` and I want to create a lookup function `k -> v` derived from this list. When the list is finite this can easily be done using foldl, however for infinite lists this seems more complicated. Consider the code below. The lookup created with `createMapCustom` terminates while the lookup created with `createMapFoldl` doesn't. Is there any way I can make it the latter will terminate?

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let infList = map (\k -> (k, "value")) [0..]
  print $ createMapCustom infList 0
  print $ createMapFoldl infList 0

createMapCustom, createMapFoldl :: Eq k => [(k, v)] -> (k -> Maybe v)

createMapCustom [] _ = Nothing
createMapCustom ((k, v):xs) k'
  | k == k'   = Just v
  | otherwise = createMapCustom xs k'

createMapFoldl = foldl (\f ~(k, v) -> f `combine` (\k' -> if k' == k then Just v else Nothing)) (const Nothing)

combine :: (a -> Maybe b) -> (a -> Maybe b) -> (a -> Maybe b)
combine f1 f2 v = case f1 v of
  Just x  -> Just x
  Nothing -> case f2 v of
    Just x2 -> Just x2
    Nothing -> Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post explains it pretty well https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/qrf54/why_does_foldr_work_on_infinite_lists_but_not/

instead of using foldl I should have used foldr as it is right-assiotive

```hs
createMapFoldr = foldr (\(k, v) f -> (\k' -> if k' == k then Just v else Nothing) `combine` f) (const Nothing)
```